# changing active class in twitter bootstrap to the current page that user clicks on in the navigation bar

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink, navigation

I am sure the answer to this question has been answered many times. In fact, I've been reading tons of threads regarding this question, but I still have no clue how to go about doing this. If you can help me with a very simple way of implementing the code, that would be awesome. I am a complete newbie at this, and have very little, if not, zero, knowledge of javascript.

I have a simple fixed navigation bar (of about 5 links) on the top of the site I'm currently building, using twitter bootstrap. This is a one-page scrollable website.

In twitter bootstrap, there is a class on the first link. This class is "active". It's there by default.
I'm assuming this is the key to highlighting the links when a user clicks on one of the links in the navbar, ie. when the user scrolls to a certain section on the 1-page website, the corresponding navigation link gets highlighted.

I think I need to add some javascript to get this working. Or maybe I can get this working without javascript?
What do I do? Please help...
If you can get an example up on jsfiddle, that would be great too.

What I need help with specifically:

1) I need to incorporate smooth-scrolling on the website (which I can kinda do, using something I've searched for online, but would prefer to have a complete solution to this including the points below).

2) When user scrolls down or up my 1-page website, the navigation links changes color, according to the section they're in.

3) When user clicks on one of these navigation links, the link remains highlighted while the user reads that section of my website.

4) If I need to use javascript, do I write the javascript at the bottom of my HTML code, above the body tag? Or should I create a new .js file?

5) I need to stress that I'm a complete newbie, and that I'm using the current version of twitter bootstrap.

Comment: Paste the code you tried, and say what you expect...

Comment: here's the basic code for what I have. I need help for what I need. Thanks! http://jsfiddle.net/LDY3N/

Answer (score 0):

Ok.

1. download http://flesler.blogspot.com/
2. download http://github.com/davist11/jQuery-One-Page-Nav

Call js

```
jQuery('#top-nav').onePageNav({
scrollSpeed: 1200,
currentClass: 'active',
changeHash: true,
filter: ':not(.external)' // used for external navigation links if any <a class="external" href=""></a>
```

});

Add id="top-nav" to your nav

Comment: Hey thanks so much for the reply and help... I went to the flesler link and should I be downloading SerialScroll, or ScrollTo? I'm assuming ScrollTo?